# How to find the index of matching string in a list java?

Tags: java, arraylist, contains, indexof

Lets say there's an array list **student** of strings like

```
["name"],
["email"],
["address:]
```

Is there a way to find the index position of list which contains the matching string ***address*** 
list.indexOf() only returns the value if the exact match of string is found.
In this case, student.indexOf("address") returns -1 since the exact match is not found.
I am aware of contains() method but it only tells if the required string is present or not. It doesn't return the index position.

Comment: So you want to implement an `indexOf()` method that takes partial matches? Edit: a partial code implementation of your own would help, since the question is a little unclear.  What do you mean by "student of strings?"  Do you have a `List<String>` or something else?

Comment: @markspace Yes, I do have a List<String>, like below
ArrayList<String> students = new ArrayList<>();
students.add("name");
students.add("email");
students.add("address");

And i guess you are the only one who followed my question

Answer (score 3):

You can search for all strings containing the search value and then call the indexOf method on every result object.

```
List<String> values = Arrays.asList("abc", "def", "ghi", "a", "ab");

List<Integer> indexes = values.stream().filter(v -> v.contains("ab")).map(v -> values.indexOf(v))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(indexes); // prints [0, 4]
```

If you just need the first index you can do

```
Integer firstIndex = values.stream().filter(v -> v.contains("ab")).map(v -> values.indexOf(v)).findFirst()
                .orElse(-1);
System.out.println(firstIndex); // prints 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `ArrayList<String>` to do that. This class contains a method called `indexOf()`. To instantiate a `ArrayList` you can do :

```
ArrayList<String> students = new ArrayList<>();
students.add("name");
students.add("email");
students.add("address");

int index = students.indexOf("address");
```

But if you don't want to use a List object, you can loop through your array with a simple for loop and check with a condition like this :

```
int index = -1;
for(int i = 0; i < students.length; i++)
    if(students[i].equals("address"))
        index = i;
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure if i got you

but is that what you looking for

```
ArrayList<String> students = new ArrayList<>();
    students.add("[\"name\"],[\"email\"],[\"addrss:]");
    students.add("[\"name\"],[\"email\"],[\"addess:]");
    students.add("[\"name\"],[\"email\"],[\"address:]");

    System.out.println(students.stream()
            .filter(s -> s.contains("address"))
            .limit(1)
            .map(students::indexOf)
            .findFirst().orElse(-1));
```

this will get you the index of the first occurrence same as indexOf do

Comment: Please explain.  After limit(1) we have a stream of just one element.  So how can .map() work on that?

Comment: ... Are we relying on the lazy computation, i.e. the internal semantics?  For example, if there was also a sort, presumably not lazy, then this would not work.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this.  Just create a method, `getIndex()` that takes the partial string and list and returns the index.

```
List<String> strings = List.of("name", "email", "address:");
String[] testData = { "ame", "ema", "add", "foo" };

for (String data : testData) {
    int i = getIndex(data, strings);
    System.out.println(i >= 0 ?
            (strings.get(i) + " found for '" + data + "'") :
            "No match for '" + data + "'");
}
```

prints

```
name found for 'ame'
email found for 'ema'
address: found for 'add'
No match for 'foo'
```

And here is the method.  Simply continuing taking items until the string contains the substring. The returned `count` is then the actual index of that string in the list.  An extra test is done to return -1 if not found.

```
public static int getIndex(String s, List<String> list) {
    int index = (int) list.stream()
            .takeWhile(str -> !str.contains(s)).count();
    return index < list.size() ? index : -1;
}
```

Note that if two strings have the same substring, the index of the first encountered will be returned.